# How to get the data without breaking the call in the Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

What I need to do to circumvent this issue, because when I request data for 2 months I already receive this error, when there is a break per day, I have the following call. With Little data works perfect, but when I increase the period the server brings me

User request limit reached","type":"OAuthException","is_transient":true,"code":17,"error_subcode":2446079,"fbtrace_id":"...

```
function solicitacaoAssicrona(){
 var service = getService()
 var batch = [{"method": "GET", "relative_url":"v3.2/act_1125789557444919/insights/impressions,reach,frequency,spend,campaign_name,account_name,clicks,cost_per_10_sec_video_view,cpm,cpp?level=campaign&since=2016-03-03&until=2019-03-04&time_increment=1&limit=100"}]
// var batchUrl = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(batch));
// Logger.log(batchUrl);
 var url = "https://graph.facebook.com?include_headers=false&batch=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(batch)) 
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {    
     Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
   }
 });
 var result =  JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); 
 Logger.log(result)
// response.forEach(function(resp){
// var resp = JSON.parse(resp.body);
// //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(resp, null, 2));
//   
////   resp.data[0].values.forEach(function(response){
////     
////   
////   }) 
//// 
// })
}
```

I'Ve looked at the documentation, but to the moment without success!
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/best-practices/

That's the call I have

```
var metricas = [
'impressions',
'reach',
'unique_clicks',
'account_currency',
'account_id',
'account_name',
'ad_id',
'ad_name',
'adset_id',
'adset_name',
'buying_type',
'campaign_id',
'campaign_name',
'clicks',
'cost_per_inline_link_click',
'cost_per_inline_post_engagement',
'cost_per_unique_click',
'cost_per_unique_inline_link_click',
'cpc', 
'cpm',
'cpp',
'ctr',
'date_start',
//'date_stop',
'frequency',
'inline_link_click_ctr',
'inline_link_clicks',
'inline_post_engagement',
'objective',
'relevance_score',
'social_spend',
'spend',
'unique_ctr',
'unique_inline_link_click_ctr',
'unique_inline_link_clicks',
'unique_link_clicks_ctr',
//'website_ctr',
'video_10_sec_watched_actions',
'cost_per_10_sec_video_view',
'video_30_sec_watched_actions',
'video_avg_percent_watched_actions',
'video_avg_time_watched_actions',
'video_p100_watched_actions',
'video_p25_watched_actions',
'video_p50_watched_actions',
'video_p75_watched_actions',
'video_play_actions',
'video_thruplay_watched_actions',
'video_p95_watched_actions', 
]

var parameters = metricas.join(',');
var url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/act_xxxxxxxxxx/insights?fields= + parameters + '&level=ad&time_range[since]=2019-02-05&time_range[until]=2019-04-05&time_increment=1&limit=200'
```

Answer (score -1):

It's to do with how much data you can retrieve with batch requests. For longer periods, you should divide it into smaller chunks, sequential to each other, thus retrieving the data needed in multiple requests. Have a look at this example:

#### Code.gs

From line 88 of the file, you can see how it can be divided in multiple requests.
https://github.com/halsandr/Facebook_Connector/blob/master/Code.gs

```
function dateDelta(dObj, num) {
    if (isNaN(num)) {
      var dateStart = new Date(dObj);
    } else {
      var dateStart = new Date(dObj);
      var dateStart = new Date(dateStart.setDate(dateStart.getDate() + num));
    }
    var dd = dateStart.getDate();
    var mm = dateStart.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
    
    var yyyy = dateStart.getFullYear();
    if(dd<10){
        dd='0'+dd;
    } 
    if(mm<10){
        mm='0'+mm;
    } 
    var dateStart = yyyy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd;
    return dateStart;
  }
  
  var gStartDate = new Date(request.dateRange.startDate);
  var gStartDate = new Date(dateDelta(gStartDate, -1));
  var gEndDate = new Date(request.dateRange.endDate);
  var gEndDate = new Date(dateDelta(gEndDate, +1));
  var gRange = Math.ceil(Math.abs(gEndDate - gStartDate) / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
  var gBatches = Math.ceil(gRange / 92);

  if (gBatches < 2) {
    var batch = [{"method": "GET", "relative_url": request.configParams.pageID + "/insights/page_fans,page_impressions,page_post_engagements?since=" + dateDelta(gStartDate) + "&until=" + dateDelta(gEndDate)}];
    //console.log(batch);
  } else {
    batch = [];
    var iterRanges = gRange / gBatches;
    
    for (i = 0; i < gBatches; i++) {
      var iterStart = dateDelta(gStartDate, (iterRanges * i));
      if (i == (gBatches - 1)) {
        var iterEnd = dateDelta(gEndDate);
      } else {
        var iterEnd = dateDelta(gStartDate, (iterRanges * (i + 1)) + 1);
      }
      batch.push({"method": "GET", "relative_url": request.configParams.pageID + "/insights/page_fans,page_impressions,page_post_engagements?since=" + iterStart + "&until=" + iterEnd})
    }
    //console.log(batch);
  }
  
    // Fetch the data with UrlFetchApp
  var url = "https://graph.facebook.com?include_headers=false&batch=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(batch))
```